# Store typealias as class type in NSHashTable

Tags: ios, swift

Lets assume i have a protocol to what only classes can confirm, using that i create `typealias` combined with some class type.

```
protocol Foo: class {}
typealias FooView = UIView & Foo
```

I would like to store instances of `UIView` conforming to this protocol in a weak hash table. So i do:

```
let hashtable = NSHashTable<FooView>.weakObjects()
```

But i receive the following error:

> 'NSHashTable' requires that 'FooView' (aka 'Foo & UIView') be a class type

I understand that `NSHashTable` only works with reference types, but what i do not get, since `UIView` is reference type and `Foo` protocol is also class type, IMHO it should be a valid declaration.

I understand, that i could just create a class like the following:

```
class FooView: UIView, Foo {}
```

And than it would probably work, however, that is not a possible solution. Does someone else have an other idea how to use `typealias` and still store it in a `HashTable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (shortened) definition of NSHashTable looks like this:

```swift
class NSHashTable<ObjectType> : NSObject where ObjectType : AnyObject
```

and the `Foo` component doesn't comply to the `AnyObject` requirement (see [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself)) for more details why protocols don't conform to other protocols).

An solution to this limitation is to use a wrapper class:

```swift
class FooViewWrapper {
    let view: FooView

    init(view: FooView) {
        self.view = view
    }
}

let hashtable = NSHashTable<FooViewWrapper>.weakObjects()
```

or via generics:

```swift
class Ref<T>{
    let value: T

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

let hashtable = NSHashTable<Ref<FooView>>.weakObjects()
```

Wrapping and unwrapping such views would add some extra code, but will work nicely with hash tables.

Comment: I was aware of this solution as well, but my aim is not to use any helper class.

Comment: @dirtydanee in that case I don't think there's a solution to the problem, due to the protocol conformance thing that I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: after doing some further research, i came to the conclusion, there is no other way. Sad :(

Answer (score -3):

What you can try is to create an extension of the UIView class which conforms to the Foo protocol:

```
protocol Foo {
    var bar: Int { get }
}

extension UIView: Foo {
    var bar = 4
}
```

And if you realy need the typealias, you can also create a typealias on the UIView class itself.

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question.